# Where can I learn the etymology behind the terminology of philosophy?

Tags: terminology

Though language can be illogical and irrational, this question presupposes against randomness
(ie: the following also applies to terminology in philosophy):

> <sub>Source: p 381, *An Introduction to Language* (10 ed, 2014) by Victoria Fromkin, Robert Rodman, Nina Hyams</sub>
>
> As we have shown. linguistic
>   changes do not happen suddenly. Speakers of English did not wake up one morning and
>   decide to use the word *beef* for “ox meat," nor do all the children of one particular generation grow up to adopt a new word. Changes are more gradual, particularly changes in
>   the phonological and syntactic system.

Conscious of the Etymological Fallacy, how can you self-learn and research possible etymologies behind terminology in philosophy (ie: reasons and histories that motivated the choice thereof)? It seems too inefficient to question every term here anew here on Philosophy SE. Etymonline and OED may list the philosophical definition for a common noun with other nonspecialist meanings, but do not reveal the semantic changes that generated the particular philosophy definition.

[This question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/30896/8572) exemplifies the aforesaid terms.

Comment: The language of Philosophy is mainly of ancient Greek and Latin source. Thus, it is necessary to read ancient philosophical texts.

Comment: Possible source : Francis Peters, [Greek Philosophical Terms: A Historical Lexicon](https://books.google.it/books?id=JepR6Mj9Hy8C&pg=PP1) (1967).

Comment: Also useful : [Liddell and Scott's lexicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Greek%E2%80%93English_Lexicon) : [8th edition](https://archive.org/stream/greekenglishlex00lidduoft#page/ii/mode/2up) or [on-line](http://stephanus.tlg.uci.edu/lsj/#eid=1&context=lsj).